Layer stack up selection for better signal integrity
I need to find an optimized stack up from the signal integrity point of view. I want provide for all of my signal tracks an adjacent GND plane. I have the following candidates for my stack up, would you please let me know which one is the best one? and why?

The device has 128 channels, and will be located on the top layer, on the bottom layer the the output connector will be place:

Considering the pitch of the device and the connector it is not possible to do it in 4 layers and I estimated roughly I would need 4 signal layers, then for each signal, I would need a GND plane, then I considered a 8 layer stack up.

Output connector:


Regards

No power routes or planes?

None of these are symmetric stackups. Are you sure they are manufacturable?

@ winny no there is no power in this design, considering the a transducer that is piezo electric and it is self sustaining regarding power. I want to make a kind of packaging for this transducer with PCB

@Tim Williams Hello Tim, thanks for the nice comment, would you please let me know what would be the symmetric version of this 8-layer board?

There is one (1) device on the board and you're asking about using eight (8) layers to wire it? Why?

@ Tim Williams the device has 128 channels, and will be located on the top layer, on the bottom layer the the output connector will be place. Considering the pitch of the device and the connector it is not possible to do it in 4 layers and I estimated rough I would need 4 signal layers, then for each signal, I would need a GND plane, then I considered a 8 layer stack up, please let me know your suggestions.

@ Tim Williams I added a lot of details in the post, so please see the edited version and let me know if everything is clear?

In stack-up #3 you appear to have lost signal layer 4. I'd go S/G/S/G/G/S/G/S.

For signal integrity questions, it's kinda useful to know what the signals are. Single ended or differential? How fast are the edge rates? How controlled impedance do they need to be? Or just, what is the protocol (eg DDR4 or whatever)?

@ Neil_UK, thank you for the nice comment, the signals are single ended, 3MHz sinusoïdal wave from, there is not controlled impedance, please let me know if you something is missing?

What is the transducer equivalent circuit? Are they all approximately equal? What is the danger if any of coupling between transducers; is there some coupling between them anyway so the electrical side isn't a concern, or must they all be well shielded, and if so to what margin (60dB, 80, 100+..)?

@Tim Williams equivalent circuit: a curent source in paraleelel with a 1nF capacitor ans 1KOhm resistor. Are they all approximately equal? yes they are all the same, What is the danger if any of coupling between transducers? We perefer not to hace any coupling and cross talk.

You don't need a GND layer for every SIG layer. For example (not doing the entire stackup here) S-G-S is a good as S-G-S-G from a signal integrity standpoint.  For you option 1, I would do S-G-S-S-G-S-S-G

I hate to get up on a soap box.  But I see too many posts like this that use terms like "best" or "no coupling".  Tim Williams (see his answer below) brings up a good point about using terms like "not to have any coupling".  This tells us you (OP) may not understand your problem well enough.  If you can't quantify it, then it's not really engineering.

From the comments,


What is the danger if any of coupling between transducers?

We prefer not to have any coupling and crosstalk. [ed]

Truly zero crosstalk/coupling is impossible; regardless of stackup, I'm afraid your design needs to be reconsidered at a more basic level.
For common signals on a connector, I would expect ballpark 60dB isolation is reasonable enough, but infinite, there's-- I mean there's not even any way to measure and confirm it.

@ Tim Williams regarding mu track width in my design, i would to choose between 0.1mm and 0.2mm would you please let me know, which one do know think is better for this design?

I'm afraid I don't have enough information to make a decision on that.
